# Javascript - Async await and fetch - return the value, not the promise?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to work with async await and fetching data using the fetch api

My problem is, I just don't quite understand how I really get the answer from the server and not the status of the promise. I get the following in the console

```
Promise {<pending>}
-------------------------------
{locale: "en"}
```

but what I rather expect is the server response which should be "locale: en".

my code:

```
const locale = getLocale();
console.log(locale) // here I want to have "locale: en" as a output


async function fetchLocale() {
    return await fetch('/get-language', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'GET',
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        }
        return Promise.reject(Error('error'))
    }).catch(error => {
        return Promise.reject(Error(error.message))
    })
}

async function getLocale() {
    return await fetchLocale();
}
```

The goal I want to archive is, to return this "locale: en" response and store it in the "locale" const at the beginning of my code example.

KR

Comment: Oh - and I'm using plain JS

Comment: your `getLocale()` function does not return anything.

Comment: Replace `console.log(response)` with `return response`, and `fetchLocale()` with `getLocale()`

Comment: ... and then understand that what you're getting back is a Promise, so you *still* won't directly get the locale. You'll need to add a `.then()` callback or else wrap the call in another immediately invoked `async` function wrapper.

Comment: Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lbyd98fo/

Comment: Oh, I've fixed the typos - there was another function called fetchLocale, where I was trying things out :D

Comment: @ChrisG I will try that.. one sec..

Comment: okay I'm still not sure, for me it doesn't work.. I will update my question with what I have now

Comment: @JuniorDev please see my or TKoL's answers. You cannot bring async results into synchronous context like the top level of your file, it just isn't possible. You need to consume the function with either `.then()` or `await` in an async function.

Comment: Exactly; just move all your code into a `main()` function, like I did. Your current code still has the original problem, you just wrapped in an additional function call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your function should look more like this:

```
async function getLocale() {
    let response = await fetch('/get-language', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'GET',
    });
    // you can check for response.ok here, and literally just throw an error if you want
    return await response.json();
}
```

And you can consume the result of that in an async function using await

```
const locale = await getLocale();
console.log(locale);
```

or by using the promise methods

```
getLocale().then(function(locale){
    console.log(locale);
})
```

Comment: If I do that, I get the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Also my IDE said: const locale = await getLocale(); is not valid JS

Comment: @JuniorDev As stated in the answer and the error, you need to use it **in an async function**. There's no way to bring it out into a synchronous context like the top level of your file.

Comment: @JuniorDev yes, put it in an async function, something like `(async () => { const locale = await getLocale(); })();` should do

Answer (score 4):

To get the value a Promise resolves with and not the promise itself, use `.then()` or `await`. Note that both require a callback or asynchronous context as it's simply not possible to bring this asynchronous result to a synchronous context such as the top level of your file.

```
getLocale().then(locale => {
    console.log(locale);
    //locale is only valid here
});
```

Comment: So it is not possible to store the output in a variable? my problem is, that depending on the current locale, I will display different texts on different languages. Thats why I thought I'm doing a fetch to get the locale at the top of my file and store it in a constant. So on every part of my JS I can display differnet texts by checking the language

Comment: @JuniorDev You can store the output in a variable, as long as you're aware that the output will **only** be assigned some time after you call `getLocale()` (could be several seconds). If you need the output immediately, you need to put all code dependent on it in the `.then()` callback or in an async function where you assign the locale at the top. This is just the nature of asynchronous javascript, restructuring your code to accommodate is a matter of course. There's several good patterns for doing this correctly, unfortunately none of them involve assigning it synchronously.

Comment: Ahh I understand! Thanks alot! :))